# "starting at just under 40 billion minutes of calls in 1995, then (rising/rised) steadily"

Tags: tense, verbs, ielts

> National and international fixed calls showed a similar pattern, starting at just under 40 billion minutes of calls in 1995, then **rising/rised** steadily to around 60 billion minutes of calls in 2002.

Which word should I use in the sentence above, "rising" or "rised"?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary for "rising" and "rised"? In fact, can you see an entry for "rised"?

Comment: to rise, rose, risen. There is no rised. There is rose.

Answer (score 1):

The (irregular) past tense of “rise” is “rose”, not “rised”.

The core of your question is this:

- starting, then rising/rose

This is semantically equivalent to:

- starting and then rising/rose

When you see a coordinating conjunction like “and”, the objects being joined need to have the same grammatical form. This is called [parallelism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)).

So, these two are allowed:

- starting and then rising
- started and then rose

But these two are not allowed:

- starting and then rose
- started and then rising

Note that faulty parallelism is quite common in practice, especially when speaking informally, so do not take the many such examples you will see as evidence of correctness.

Comment: No, you cannot say *started and then rose* in that sentence, because the clause *started at just under 40 billion minutes of calls* needs a subject.

Comment: @PeterShor He did not state that "started and then rose" is allowed in *this* sentence, just that it is allowed in the general context of grammar.